# Ajax response set on datatable columns

Tags: php, database, datatables, datatables-1.10

Ajax call code:

```
$.ajax({

          type: 'POST',
          url: '{{BASE_URL}',
          data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "from" :from,
                "to"   :to
          },
          success: function (response)
           {


           }

          })
        })
```

my datatbale fields given below:

i am not able to display the data in datatable can anyone please help me related this how can i set the ajax response data in datatable

```
html code for datatable:
```

datatable design question updated i want the result in these fields but not getting the exact way

Comment: can you include the html code for your datatable ?

Comment: I think you are not appending the value to your table

Comment: @xanadev see updated code

Comment: @parthi thats what i am asking to u .. how can i append the value to table

Comment: if i understand your question, you want to issue and ajax request to your php code then append the result to your datatable right ?

Comment: i am getting the respone in proper way i want only to set my response in datatable

Comment: @xanadev in a way ur getting my points..

Comment: well what i don't understand is that you are filling the table using php, then you make an ajax call to retrieve some additional data, do you want to append the data fetched by ajax into the already existing data on the table, or maybe you are looking for a way to fill the datatable using only an ajax request, which would be a better solution. i can help :)

Comment: @Shruti i think your problem  is when you appending response then datatable not working

Comment: @ R B yes ur right

Comment: then you just reload the datatable

Comment: after ajax response

Comment: i i will reload the table searching data will not able to display

Comment: if appending the data is what you really want to do then try https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()

Comment: @Shruti i posted ans

Comment: @ xanadev can you please update my question with answer >?

Comment: @Shruti did you solve your problem? sorry i was busy, i couldn't write a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just use this code when getting ajax call success response.

```
                    var table = $("#agent tbody");
                     $.each(response, function (idx, elem) {

                         table.append("<tr><td>" + elem.agent_id + "</td> <td>" + elem.fname_eng + "</td> <td>" + elem.mname_eng
                             + "</td> <td>" + elem.lname_eng + "</td> <td>" + elem.email + "</td> <td>"
                             + elem.bussiness_civil_no_eng + "</td> <td>" + elem.uco-123 + "</td> <td>");

                     });
```

Comment: its searching the value but not filtering the data in table can u please update my question ??

Answer (score 0):

After ajax response reinitialize the datatable like

```
success: function(data) {
 $("tbody").append(data);
 $('#agent').DataTable({ 
 "destroy": true, //use for reinitialize datatable
});
```

Comment: @ RB data showing in response way but old table not getting destroy

Comment: reinitialize your datatable not use destroy like `$('#agent').DataTable();`

Comment: @Shruti what you want you don't want old data

Comment: then don't use `append()` use `html()`